OpenCL giving segmentation fault on creating buffer
I am trying to convert an image to greyscale using opencl. But when i am attempting to create the readbuffer. i am getting a segmentation fault even though the buffer size is well within the memory limits of the device. i tried on width = 4000 and height = 6000
This is my opencl function.
The segfault appears on this line
cl::Buffer input_buffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY | CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR, sizeof(uchar) * width * height * 3, input, &err);

void executeOpenCL(uchar*** input, uchar** output, const int height, const int width)
{
    cl_int err;
    std::vector<cl::Platform> platforms;
    err = cl::Platform::get(&platforms);
 
    cl::Platform platform = platforms[0]; // Choose the first platform
    std::vector<cl::Device> devices;
    err = platform.getDevices(CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU, &devices);

    cl::Device device = devices[0]; // Choose the first GPU device
    cl::Context context(device);
    cl::CommandQueue queue(context, device);

    // Create OpenCL buffers for input and output image data
    cl::Buffer input_buffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY | CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR, sizeof(uchar) * width * height * 3, input, &err);

    return;
}

I tried to check whether the buffer size is greater than the memory of the host device but even if that is within the limit.
Input as defined as an unsigned char3d array
    uchar*** array3D = new uchar** [height];
    for (int i = 0; i < height; ++i) {
        array3D[i] = new uchar* [width];
        for (int j = 0; j < width; ++j) {
            array3D[i][j] = new uchar[3]; // Assuming 3 channels (RGB)
        }
    }


this line
cl::Buffer input_buffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY | CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR, sizeof(uchar) * width * height * 3, input, &err);

Such questions should be posted with [mcve]s. How is input defined, does it suitable for the given width and hight?

Does the std::cout << i + 1 << ". " << devices[i].getInfo line output correct and expected information?

yes. it outputs the expected information.

@273K followed mre and added def of input

You have a lot of err returns after the call, but you don't check them. From experience, even if it seems to work, not checking them is not good practice as they may hide some side effects later on. Can you cout the err result and include it as inline comments after you re-execute the MRE, just for good measure, please?

uchar*** array3D = new uchar** [height];  Why?  I would expect OpenCL to expect a contiguous memory bufffer (not some chopped up bits of memory all over the place). E.g. a std::vector<std::uint8_t,width*height*3> buffer; (and then pass buffer.data() to your API). Side note : using naked new/delete is really not recommended in C++ anymore

@TheNomad i did check them earlier when executing the code but only removed them because of mre.

Here is your mistake
uchar*** array3D = new uchar** [height];
for (int i = 0; i < height; ++i) {
    array3D[i] = new uchar* [width];
    for (int j = 0; j < width; ++j) {
        array3D[i][j] = new uchar[3]; // Assuming 3 channels (RGB)
    }
}

It must be a continuous memory buffer
uchar* array3D = new uchar[width * height * 3];


i did this but i am still getting same error

"I did this" is very vague, show a [mcve] of what you did.
